# How to get OS X notifications for babel watch from npm run script?

Tags: macos, notifications, npm, watch, babeljs

We are running `babel --watch` with npm scripts.

Is there an (easy) way to get OS X notifications (Mavericks or El Capitan) on errors, something like [gulp-notify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-notify)?

Answer (score 1):

No, `babel` program (now [`babel-cli`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-cli)) does not provide a way to hook custom callbacks for events such as errors. Instead, you can use [`gulp-babel`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-babel) to abstract your build tasks.